# How to get the available wi-fi list and there images of strength as it shows in android phone

Tags: android, android-wifi, background-service

How to get the available wi-fi list and there images of strength as it shows in android phone

and how to achieve the feature of scning for wi-fi in background and switch to other available wi-fi is connected wi-fi is no longer available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Android Wifi Scan Results into a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452940/how-can-i-get-android-wifi-scan-results-into-a-list)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286604/get-wifis-ssid-without-connecting-to-it

Comment: Its not exactly what i want