# How to search and connect to a specific wifi network in Android programmatically

Tags: android, wifi

If this is the layout of the app, and when the wifi is turned on, I want the list of networks available and then to connect to it by selecting any of them

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**Search for available wifi networks**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    WifiManager mainWifi;
    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        if(mainWifi.isWifiEnabled()==false)
        {
            mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }


        doInback();
    }

    public void doInback()
    {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

                receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
                registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
                        WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
                mainWifi.startScan();
                doInback();
            }
        }, 1000);

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);}
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        mainWifi.startScan();

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);}


    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }

    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
        {

            ArrayList<String> connections=new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<Float> Signal_Strenth= new ArrayList<Float>();

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            List<ScanResult> wifiList;
            wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++)
            {

                connections.add(wifiList.get(i).SSID);
            }


        }
    }



}
```

**create WifiConfiguration instance**

```
 WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
```

**for WEP network**

```
    conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPass + "\""; 
conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
```

**For WPA network**

```
conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
```

**For Open network**

```
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
```

**add it to Android wifi manager**

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
```

**enable it**

```
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
    if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
         wifiManager.disconnect();
         wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
         wifiManager.reconnect();               

         break;
    }           
 }
```

Comment: private final Handler handler = new Handler()  - getting error at this line i.e handler is abstract cannot be instantiated

Comment: error showing at  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() , cannot resolve method postDelayed

Comment: I ve edited the code part about handler, and do not wait for someone to do the exact code for you. Consider this as just a thread that help you to achieve your need.

Comment: why do we iterate through a list instead of just adding the network once we configure it?

Answer (score 0):

From the first page get only third example for scanning available wifi it worked for me and I modify it to choose specific `BSSID` by using:

```
[bssid = wifiScanList.get(i).BSSID;
    if (desiredMacAddress.equals(bssid)){ APPEND TO SHOWING LIST...}
]
```

it tests it and it worked without problems+ gave what i wanted. 
from the second page get how to join desired access point it try it then it work with out any problems but I can't sure it gives me this functionality

[Get WiFi's SSID without connecting to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286604/get-wifis-ssid-without-connecting-to-it)

one final thing if you tested second on a real device it will change its setting which will lead to problems