# Mobile App to verify and/or send WiFi settings?

Tags: android, ios, wifi

I have a client that configures and deploys handheld scanners to remote locations. We have to pre-configure them to work on a local WiFi network. For these scanners we must manually configure SSID, Encrypted Password, and Encryption Type. We also need to know the Network/DHCP info (Subnet Mask, Default Gateway).

Unfortunately, we are often working with people who are not very tech savvy to provide us with their Wifi Information and they often provide us with incorrect or incomplete info.

So I'm wondering, could we write an App (or even better if there's already something that exists, though admittedly a long shot) that would prompt the User to enter the SSID and password and then would verify that it's connecting to the Access point and getting an IP Address... and then send us all of the configuration information via email (or http post? Or save it to a local file that the user could send to us?) so we can be certain we have the correct info before we ship the scanners?

Comment: this might help you with the android side of things:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098871/how-to-search-and-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically

Comment: I think you are searching something like this: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8818490/5343320)