# WifiManager returns an empty list on my Xperia Z3+ but works as expected on my Galaxy S4

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

My `WifiBroadcastReceiver` listens for updated WIFI states. when I press a button on my `MainActivity` a WIFI scan is performed by `WifiManager`, which triggers the `onReceive` method in my WifiBroadcastReceiver.
When I get the `action` from the `Intent`, it is correct, it returns `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`. When I receive that `action` I call `WifiManager.getScanResults()` which returns a `List` of `ScanResult` objects.

On the S4 the results are as expected, a list of available WIFI networks. However on the Z3+, while it does return a `List<ScanResult>` the list is empty.

What could be causing this?

The S4 is running Android 5.0.1.
The Z3+ is running Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, the designers of Android phones did not all do "the same thing" in "the same way."  Less-expensive phones, and phones from different manufacturers in general, do not always work like the super-duper phones that developers often have in *their* pockets.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid this was the type of answer I was going to get. But this seem to be a difference at quite a low level, I would have hoped that this type of thing would be standard, for something as ubiquitous as scanning for Wifi networks.

Comment: Obviously, look *very* carefully for error-logs of any sort, but, "yes, it's goofy what the differences are, sometimes."

Comment: You are correct! I turned off the logcat filters then the issue was obvious. I need coarse and fine grained position permissions to retrieve results.

Comment: Well, as it turns out the app already had those permissions, so I'm back to square 1.

Comment: Ok looks like this is the issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151603/scan-results-available-action-return-empty-list-in-android-6-0

Comment: Then I suggest that you add this as an "Answer."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Android 6.0 permission behaviour has moved to runtime. This means we need to handle permissions differently.

See this answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32151901/571875