# wifiManager.getScanResults() returns 0 in Android 6.0.1, Samsung S5

Tags: android, wifimanager

In Android 6.0.1, Samsung S5, `WifiManager.getScanResults()` returns 0. But, in Android 6.0.1, Nexus phone, it works pretty well. If I turn on the `GPS` on Samsung S5 , then it also works and return the valid scan result list.

But, i think, its not a good idea to turn on GPS. So, I want to know the right way to use `getScanResults` for obtaining the scan results.

N.B. I gave `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` , `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission as instructed on developer site.

Comment: check permission manually in settings!!

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151603/scan-results-available-action-return-empty-list-in-android-6-0

Comment: How you find it as duplicate with that question? I already mentioned "But, in Android 6.0.1, Nexus phone, it works pretty well." The problem is, in 6.0.1 some devices return the valid scan results and some returns 0. Besides this, i mentioned turning on GPS it works but i am not interested to do that. @mfruizs2

Comment: See the link below on my last reply.

Comment: We are having the same issue with a Samsung Galaxy S5. Nexus phones and a variety of tablets running Android 6.0.1+ work fine. Samsung Galaxy S4 running Lollipop also works fine. The code uses the new Android 6.0+ permission behavior for wifi scanning, but still no results ever come back specifically on Samsung Galaxy S5. We haven't tried the GPS fix, nor newer Samsung Galaxy phones.

Answer (score 6):

You can see at google docs , As of Android 6.0, permission behaviour has changed to runtime. To use a feature that requires a permission, one should check first if the permission is granted previously. Using `checkSelfPermission(permissionString)` [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)) a result is returned, wither ther permission is `PERMISSION_GRANTED` or `PERMISSION_DENIED`.

If permission isn't granted or it is first time, a request for permission should be made. Giving a user an option to grant or deny.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
   requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                 PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method

}else{
    getScanningResults();
   //do something, permission was previously granted; or legacy device
}
```

If your code is running on device prior to M, you proceed with your code, permission was granted using legacy method.

Once requested for permission, dialog will be shown to user. His/her response will be delivered as:

```
@Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
         int[] grantResults) {
     if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
             && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         // Do something with granted permission
        mWifiListener.getScanningResults();
     }
 }
```

After that, you can check if the Location Services is ON, using `LocationServices.SettingsApi` and request the user to enable if this options is disabled. This is possible with Play Services `LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` callback.