# Get List of Available WiFi networks without location services in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, wifimanager

**EDIT:**
I know that SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION returns a list of size '0' if location services are off.The question was how to do it without location services.

**PREVIOUS:**
I need a list of all available WiFi networks to the phone,and use that list to populate a `ListView` in my app. I will later connect to the desired network from my app.

I have achieved the above by using ,

```
 wifiManager.startScan();
```

and I have registered a BroadcastReciever for receiving an intimation when a scan is complete like below,

```
registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
```

receiver code is as follows,

```
 class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        // This method call when number of wifiManager connections changed
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            wifiResults.clear();
            wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
                if(!wifiList.get(i).SSID.equals(""))
                wifiResults.add(wifiList.get(i).SSID+" signal:"+wifiList.get(i).level);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            wifiRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    }
```

the problem is I am having to enable location services every time I want the above information.I don't really see the point here as I don't need the location services here as other apps like "SHAREit" do the same without needing location services .Is there a better approach for achieving this?

Comment: SHAREit does request location services

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCAN\_RESULTS\_AVAILABLE\_ACTION return empty list in Android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151603/scan-results-available-action-return-empty-list-in-android-6-0)

Comment: @nitzanms no shareit does'nt require location services

Comment: Look at the permissions list in app details in the Android play store. It has fine and coarse location listed.

Comment: Yes it is listed ,But it is not present in the permissions list after installation.

Answer (score 2):

We can get the list of available **WIFI** without **GPS** turned on by setting the app's **targetSDKversion** to 21 or lower.

Comment: Thanks, But that is not an option, as I want the latest target sdk version