# Android O issues with WiFi Peer Discovery

Tags: android-wifi, wifi-direct, service-discovery, wifip2p, android-8.0-oreo

I am developing an Android Application that employs WiFi (Direct) for service discovery and P2P peer discovery/connection.

My development enviromment is as follows:-

```
Android Studio 3.0 Beta 4
Build #AI-171.4304935, built on August 29, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.11.6
```

My Gradle build:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.research.wifi_direct"

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "INSTANCE_NAME", "\"_vascodagama\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVICE_TYPE", "\"_presence._tcp\""
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.7'

    implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

The devices I am testing on include:-

```
Nexus 7 - Android 6.0.1
Nexus 9 - Android 7.1.1
Samsung Tablet - Android 4.4.1
Pixel - Android 8.0.0
```

The service discovery works fine on all four devices.

However the P2P Peers List is always empty on the `Pixel XL` running `Android 8.0.0`.
The other three devices consistently discover each other as well as other miscellaneous devices
around my office e.g. such as a Samsung TV and my colleagues personal phones etc..

The only thing I can think of is that theres something about `Android O` that inhibits P2P peers being discovered.
I cannot see anything in the "Whats New In Android O" to identify the culprit

Has anyone seen this behaviour on `Android O`? What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

The code I am basing my application on is to be found here

https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html
https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html

Something odd that I noticed was that when I tried to keep the WiFi "stack" awake using an `android.net.wifi.WifiManager.WifiLock`
my application stopped working altogether. Further more I had to power off all my devices and restart them once I had removed the
associated WiFiLock code. And yes... I did add uses-permission `android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"`.

UPDATE - 0001

Whats odd is that when I log out the extras available in my Broadcast Receiver for PEER_CHANGED I can see the available peers listed as shown here when the Android O Pixel XL has discovered my Nexus

```
WiFiDirectBroadcastRcvr: android.net.wifi.p2p.PEERS_CHANGED<<<<<EXTRA DATA :: ------------------------START
WiFiDirectBroadcastRcvr: EXTRA DATA :: wifiP2pDeviceList 
                         Device: Nexus 7
                          deviceAddress: da:50:e6:7c:56:4e
                          primary type: 000A0050F2040005
                          secondary type: null
                          wps: 392
                          grpcapab: 0
                          devcapab: 37
                          status: 3
                          wfdInfo: WFD enabled: trueWFD DeviceInfo: 0
                          WFD CtrlPort: 0
                          WFD MaxThroughput: 0 (android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList)
WiFiDirectBroadcastRcvr: EXTRA DATA :: ------------------------FINISH
```

However when I then make my subsequent call to requestPeers I always receive an empty `WifiP2pDeviceList`?

```
case WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION:
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION");
                mWiFiPeer2PeerCommander.requestPeers(mWifiP2pManager, mWifiP2pManagerChannel);
                break;
```

Am I supposed to use the `WifiP2pDeviceList` from the passed Extra an not bother to call `requestPeers`?

Comment: How you have solved this problem in android 6.0 and above. I am not getting peer list in some of the devices which has the Android version more than 6.0. Please share the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. On my nexus 5x now also Android O.
And I also always got an empty WifiP2pDeviceList.
I think it's assign (?) with similar problem on Android 6
[SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION return empty list in Android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151603/scan-results-available-action-return-empty-list-in-android-6-0)

It works for me...

Answer (score 1):

Set the targetSdkVersion <= 25 can solve this issue,but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. I fixed it by adding

Step 1 : Add Location permission in manifest.

Step 2: Request permission dynamically in your activity.

Step 3: Now scan for WIFI peers. It will appear.

Kudos!!!