# Android: WifiP2PManager how to add peerList to a ListView

Tags: java, android, wifip2p

### Intro

Hey, I'm trying to build a Wifi-Direct P2P client which is receiving data from a host. Before I'm getting the data I need to establish a connection and the host should be the group owner (go_intent=15). Before establishing the connection I need to know if it's the device I'm looking for or not. For test purposes I wanted to display all devices in my area which are in discovery mode. That means I have to put myself in discovery mode aswell to able to be discovered from other devices.

So far I am starting the discovery mode in my `MainActivity.class` with `startFindPeers()` as soon as I turn on the switch or when my wifi is coming up again when the switch is on.

While the switch is on I should be discoverable even when I close the app and clear the RAM as long my wifi is still on.

### Problem

My Problem lies in the `WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener` which is triggered as soon as the `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` in my `WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.class` is triggered.
I can check if new peers are nearby with that callback function which is triggering my `peerListListener`.

In the `peerListListener` itself the `onPeersAvailable` function triggers which should add all the new peers to my ListView in my `activity_main.xml` but it doesn't.

Any suggestions?

### Code

Manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.tu_chemnitz.dayliehelperprototype">

    <!-- Need to permission to restart JobServices after phone being shut down -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <!-- Permissions to use WIFI-Direct -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Google Play filtering -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".JobSchedulerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.15">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:text="@string/main_page_titel"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="@string/feature_option_1"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:gravity="center|start"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center|end">
                    <Switch
                        android:id="@+id/notify_switch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:switchMinWidth="52dp"
                        android:theme="@style/mySwitchStyle"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="30dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.15">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Discovered Devices"
                        android:gravity="center|start"
                        android:textSize="28sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.85">
                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/peerListView"
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.class

```java
package de.tu_chemnitz.dayliehelperprototype;

import.*

import de.tu_chemnitz.dayliehelperprototype.utils.Utility;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String NETWORK_STATE = "NETWORK_STATE";

    // UI elements
    Switch switchNotify;
    ListView listView;

    //Wifi Direct
    WifiP2pManager manager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
    String[] deviceNameArray;
    WifiP2pDevice[] deviceArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // define UI elements
        switchNotify =  findViewById(R.id.notify_switch);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.peerListView);

        initializeWifiDirect();

        // define toolbar
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

        //load default switch states [false], otherwise get it from sharedPreferences
        boolean state = Utility.getBool(this, "switch_states", "notify_switchkey");
        switchNotify.setChecked(state);

        switchNotify.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
            if(!peerList.getDeviceList().equals(peers)){
                peers.clear();
                peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

                deviceNameArray = new String[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                deviceArray = new WifiP2pDevice[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                int index = 0;
                // maybe we can get more information here
                for(WifiP2pDevice device : peerList.getDeviceList()){
                    deviceNameArray[index] = device.deviceName;
                    deviceArray[index] = device;
                    index++;
                }
                Log.d("this is my array", "arr: " + Arrays.toString(deviceNameArray));
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceNameArray);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            if(peers.size() == 0){
                Log.d("WIFIDIRECT", "No devices found");
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     *   OnCheckedListeners for the switches
     */
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                if(Utility.isWiFiEnabled(MainActivity.this)){
                    Utility.customToastMsg(MainActivity.this,"Enabled", "#1abc9c");

                    startFindPeers();
                }
                else{
                    switchNotify.setChecked(false);
                    Utility.customToastMsg(MainActivity.this,"Wifi is disabled", "#FFB900");
                    isChecked = false;
                }

            } else {
                Utility.customToastMsg(MainActivity.this,"Disabled", "#ef5350");

                stopFindPeers();
            }
            // save current state [checked/unchecked]
            Utility.saveBool(MainActivity.this, "switch_states", "notify_switchkey", isChecked);
        }
    };


    public void startFindPeers(){
        if(manager != null){
            manager.discoverPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d(NETWORK_STATE, "Peer Discovery started");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    Log.d(NETWORK_STATE, "Peer Discovery starting failed, failcode: " + reason);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void stopFindPeers(){
        if(manager != null){
            manager.stopPeerDiscovery(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d(NETWORK_STATE, "Peer Discovery stopped");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    Log.d(NETWORK_STATE, "Peer Discovery stopping failed, failcode: " + reason);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void initializeWifiDirect(){
        //Wifi Direct
        // This clall provides the API for managing Wifi peer-to-peer connectivity.
        manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        // A channel that connects the application to the Wifi p2p framework.
        // Most p2p operations require a channel as an argument.
        if (manager != null) {
            channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        }

        receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);

        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    }
}
```

WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.class

```java
package de.tu_chemnitz.dayliehelperprototype;

import.*

/**
 * A BroadcastReceiver that notifies of important wifi p2p events.
 */
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private MainActivity activity;

    private static final String TAG = "WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver";

    /**
     * @param manager  WifiP2pManager system service
     * @param channel  Wifi p2p channel
     * @param activity activity associated with the receiver
     */
    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,MainActivity activity){
        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
     * android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED && Utility.getBool(activity, "switch_states", "notify_switchkey")) {
                activity.startFindPeers();
            }
            else {

            }
            Log.d(TAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);
        }
        else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an
            // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a
            // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.requestPeers(channel, activity.peerListListener);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "P2P peers changed");
        }
        else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        }
        else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to print the peerList in onPeersAvailable?

Comment: Yes, first I tried to print a log to see if the peerListener is triggering which was the case and afterwards I wanted to print peerList.getDevice().size() but the list was empty every time even if the other device was able to see me through Wifi-Direct.

Comment: For instance you can read the peers from /proc/net/arp file

Comment: I tried this [retrieve-ip-and-mac-addresses](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/12/retrieve-ip-and-mac-addresses-from.html) but it only showed my routers IP/MAC adress.
I think it has something to do with either the registerReceiver functions when I call them or I read something about permission which need to be checked before executing a function which requires permissions.

Comment: That doesn't require any permission

Comment: Directory do cat /proc/net/arp from terminal

Comment: No I mean my peerList problem.
cat /proc/net/arp gave me the router adress I am connected to. There's nothing else in the table.

Comment: That means your system didn't add any peers

Comment: Yea that's why the peerList is empty and I don't know why ^^

Answer (score 0):

I found my error.

Basically my code was correct, but it has something to do with the Android Version.
I executed my application on a Android Oreo (API 26) device and it didn't work like I mentioned. The peerList still was empty.

Today I tried it with a Android Nougat (API 24-25) Device and it worked!
The peerList is getting the devices nearby like it should.

In the end I set my maxSDKVersion to 25 and now it works on my Android Oreo device.

I cannot really say why its behaving like this but I think is has something to do with [permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#rmp).

**EDIT**:

Nevermind on my search journey I came to this problem in Android O+ issued here
[Peer discovery Issue with Oreo (Android 8+)](https://github.com/sabzo/ayanda/issues/17) and the solution is that you need the permission for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` mentioned here [SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION return empty list in Android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151603/scan-results-available-action-return-empty-list-in-android-6-0).

Answer (score 0):

```html
        val locationPermissionRequest = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
        ) { permissions ->
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                when {
                    permissions.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false) -> {
                        // Precise location access granted.
                        Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted to ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                    }
                    permissions.getOrDefault(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, false) -> {
                        // Only approximate location access granted.
                        Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted to ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION")
                    }
                    else -> {
                        // No location access granted.
                        Log.i(TAG, "Permission not")
                        //Send a Throwable here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        locationPermissionRequest.launch(
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            )
        )
```

Encountered the same problem and it's because the android version N > requires different approach in permission request. Peer list doesn't get filled because at some point the permission request failed. Solved it using this snippet.