# Android Studio WifiManager

Tags: java, android, wifimanager

I want to search available wifi networks and show them in a list when I click the start button in my application, but my code never finds any WiFi network. I tried to show number of available networks with `TextView` or `Toast`, but a `0` is always shown.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Listview
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView list;
    private ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListAdapter adapter1;
    TextView tV;

    //Wifi
    private WifiManager mywifi;
    WifiReceiver myreceiver;
    List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    StringBuilder sb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //definieren
        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);

        //Listview
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lV);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mylist);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Textview
        tV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tV);
        tV.setText("");

        //Wifi
        mywifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (mywifi.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wifi is disabled ....making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mywifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        myreceiver = new WifiReceiver();
        registerReceiver(myreceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        mywifi.startScan();

        //buttenevents
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //getWifiNetworksList();
            }
        });

    }

    public void getWifiNetworksList() {
        tV.setText("Wifi is starting");
        tV.setText(myreceiver.Wifilist());

    }

    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public String txt;

        // This method call when number of wifi connections changed
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            wifiList = mywifi.getScanResults();
            sb.append("\n        Number Of Wifi connections :" + wifiList.size() + "\n\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++) {

                sb.append(new Integer(i + 1).toString() + ". ");
                sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
                sb.append("\n\n");
            }

            tV.setText(sb);//tV...TextView
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "reciever finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public String Wifilist() {
            return txt;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18741306/4101906) to create your broadcastreciver, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7527380/4101906) to show results in listview

Comment: i tried both links. But i still get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Enable Location Permission.

The code works absolutely fine. Tested on Nexus 5.
I just added following permissions on Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

If it is still not showing any result. Just make sure that your User has allowed Location permission to your app.
**You can do this two ways**

> Manually

Go to settings in your phone and hit **Enable** option for the app. (In my case my app name is WifiSolution).

[image]

> Programmatically

You can also use [Android Runtime Permission](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions) to do it programmatically.