# Android: how to write code to connect router hardware

Tags: java, android

I am using Android Studio. I want to write code to connect router hardware. Does anybody can help? I have written code to connect router then I am facing error following.
E/debug: failed to connect to /192.168.0.101 (port 60123): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic. There are multiple approaches when you are talking to connect to a router.
If you want to perform operations as connecting to a router,listing all available networks available,creating your own network(hotspot) You should checkout the official documentation of android on WifiManager -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html
Or You can see this example -> [how to get available wifi networks and display them in a list in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741034/how-to-get-available-wifi-networks-and-display-them-in-a-list-in-android) after you get the basic undestanding.
If you want to connect to other devices through router you should study sockets and TCP/IP protocols,Socket implementation on JAVA.
Hope this might help.
Peace