# How to scan wifi networks in android programming by mac?

Tags: android, bufferedreader, android-wifi

can any one suggest me how to get all network connected to my wifi . i want to identify specific network among them and then that all specific network should display in listview.

Comment: you means you need to display list of all wifi available in your range ? right?

Comment: Thanks for rep , ya exactly among that i want choose one of vender .

Comment: from that you want to connect any wifi with password right ?

Comment: no, I want choose one wifi vender and then I want to take IP address of it and then I want communicate with it through udp wit

Comment: similar like chat ? you need to communicate in group or single person.

Comment: ya it will be single. see what I am doing is there will some wifi devices connected to same router so by my android app I want detect that all wifi devices In one listView get their IP Addresses and I want to communicate them through UDP massage . so how come I detect all IP's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get available wifi networks and display them in a list in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741034/how-to-get-available-wifi-networks-and-display-them-in-a-list-in-android)

Comment: no above query is related to scanning list of available network router around our device but my question is I want to scan all device connected to router to which my is already been connected . so anyone suggest in this regard ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample how to get wifi connected devices ip

https://github.com/SupunArunoda/ChatWithoutInternet

```
    private WifiApiManager wifiApManager;

       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_sharing);

        wifiApManager = new WifiApiManager(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        username = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("name");


        SelectClient sendImage = new SelectClient();
        sendImage.execute((Void) null);

    }



    //Asynchronous class to select Client
    private class SelectClient extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            final ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients = wifiApManager.getClientList(false);


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    ClientScanResult clientScanResult;
                    values = new String[clients.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
                        clientScanResult = clients.get(i);
                        values[i] = "IpAddress: " + clientScanResult.getIpAddress();//store client's ip addresses in values array
                    }
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ClientSelectActivity.this, R.layout.list_white_text, R.id.list_content, values);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            i = new Intent(ClientSelectActivity.this, PrivateChatActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("ipAddress",clients.get(position).getIpAddress());
                            i.putExtra("name", username);
                            startActivity(i);//start activity from this activity to PrivateChatActivity

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    }

    //class to manage WiFi technology
    public class WifiApiManager {
        private final WifiManager mWifiManager;

        public WifiApiManager(Context context) {
            mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        }

        public ArrayList<ClientScanResult> getClientList(boolean onlyReachables) {
            return getClientList(onlyReachables, 300);
        }

        //function to return available clients
        public ArrayList<ClientScanResult> getClientList(boolean onlyReachables, int reachableTimeout) {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            ArrayList<ClientScanResult> result = null;

            try {
                result = new ArrayList<>();
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] splitted = line.split(" +");

                    if ((splitted != null) && (splitted.length >= 4)) {
                        // Basic sanity check
                        String mac = splitted[3];

                        if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                            boolean isReachable = InetAddress.getByName(splitted[0]).isReachable(reachableTimeout);

                            if (!onlyReachables || isReachable) {
                                result.add(new ClientScanResult(splitted[0], splitted[3], splitted[5], isReachable));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, I have checked with above code  but that's not to which I intended to work . I need list of devices connected to my router to which my mobile already been connected so do you have any suggestion in this regard .

Comment: Please follow this link it larger project you need to understand form scratch, it work fine what actually you need. https://github.com/Marlinski/Rumble

Comment: I need list of device IP or Vendor name connected to my router to which mobile wifi already been connected .