# How to get list of all wifi connections available?

Tags: android, wifi

I want to get list of all wifi connections available in my app but i am not getting any list. My wifi connection is getting on and also connecting to my wifi but I am not able to get the list of wifi connections in my application.
Can anyone tell me why so? Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    WifiManager wm;
    ToggleButton tb;
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    ListView l;
    private static final int ENABLE_REQUEST=1;
    private static final int DISCOVERABLE_REQUEST=2;
    private static final int DISCOVERABLE_DURATION=120;

    BroadcastReceiver br=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action=intent.getAction();
            if(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
                List<ScanResult> hotspot=  wm.getScanResults();

                for(int i=0;i<hotspot.size();i++) {
                    aa.add(hotspot.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tb= (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
        aa=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        l.setAdapter(aa);

        wm= (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        tb.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tb= (ToggleButton) v;

        if(wm==null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This feature is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tb.setChecked(false);
        } else {
            if (tb.isChecked()) {
                wm.setWifiEnabled(true);
                discover();
            } else {
                wm.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void discover() {

        wm.startScan();
        IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        this.registerReceiver(br,filter);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741034/how-to-get-available-wifi-networks-and-display-them-in-a-list-in-android#18741306) in another stackoverflow post.

As the answer suggests, you can get your list in `mScanResults` which you can apply to your `ArrayAdapter` and finally call `setAdapter` method on the listview.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mWifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
        List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
        // add your logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Please follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741034/how-to-get-available-wifi-networks-and-display-them-in-a-list-in-android#18741306) for more details.