# How to get available wifi list from backend android service?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app which needs to check available wifi list periodically even when the app is killed from background. So I am thinking about using a service to check it from back end. In this case I am facing some problem to get the available wifi list from service. I search over internet and found most of the solution for activity only. Though I tried them but not working.

Please note that. THIS SAME CODE WORKS WHEN I USE THEM IN DIRECT ACTIVITY. BUT IT DOESN'T WORK IN SERVICE CLASS.

Code of my service is.....

```
package com.example.sodrulaminshaon.ringmodecontroller;


import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by Sodrul Amin Shaon on 22-Jun-18.
 */

public class MyService extends Service {
WifiManager wifiManager;
WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
private static final String LIST_TESTING = "ListTest";
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCE_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean auto = preferences.getBoolean(Constants.AUTO_CONTROL_STR,false);
    //if(MainActivity.getAutoControl())
    if(auto)
    {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
        {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        Log.i(LIST_TESTING,"Wifi is enabled. Now going to check the available list.");
        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi,
                new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        wifiManager.startScan();
    }
    stopSelf();
    return START_STICKY;
}

class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // This method call when number of wifi connections changed
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        List<ScanResult> wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        Log.i(LIST_TESTING,"Inside scan result receiver. Scan result size: "+wifiList.size());
        sb.append("\n        Number Of Wifi connections :"+wifiList.size()+"\n\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){

            sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ". ");
            sb.append(wifiList.get(i).SSID).toString();
            sb.append("\n\n");
        }
        Log.i(LIST_TESTING,sb.toString());
    }


}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // I want to restart this service again in one hour
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCE_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean auto = preferences.getBoolean(Constants.AUTO_CONTROL_STR,false);
    if(auto)
    {
        if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.set(
                alarm.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 10),
                PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyService.class), 0)
        );
    }
}
```

}

No need to worry about permission. I have taken necessary permissions at the start of the app. Still I am sharing the permission taken part.

```
private void getPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        askForLocationPermissions();
    }
}
private void askForLocationPermissions() {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Location permessions needed")
                .setMessage("you need to allow this permission!")
                .setPositiveButton("Sure", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Not now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .show();

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can not proceed! i need permission" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
public static boolean isPermissionGranted(@NonNull String[] grantPermissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults,
                                          @NonNull String permission) {
    for (int i = 0; i < grantPermissions.length; i++) {
        if (permission.equals(grantPermissions[i])) {
            return grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I can assure that my service is running well. It tries to check available wifi list each 10 seconds interval.

What I want to know is that. This code can not print the available wifi list. Just for the information in MyService class

```
Log.i(LIST_TESTING,"Wifi is enabled. Now going to check the available list.");
```

this line is printing continuously. But the other two lines

```
Log.i(LIST_TESTING,"Inside scan result receiver. Scan result size: "+wifiList.size());
Log.i(LIST_TESTING,sb.toString());
```

are not being executed. Can anyone please help me....

Comment: When you have *not working code*, then put up a [mcve]. We have no idea what you have read, what you have tried, and why that isn't working. So please do not expect us to repeat what was written down before . You also should spent some time at the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Not like this.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your advise. I have edited my question. Please check now and see if you can help me. As you have marked this question as duplicate I am assuring you that this code runs in activity real fine. But not working in service.

Answer (score 1):

As nobody is answering. I tried further and found the problem of my code. In my code I called 
    `stopSelf();`
inside 
   `public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` method. Which was causing my service to stop just after it was started. Which means my registered `broadCastReceiver` was also being discarded. As a result wifi list was not being printed. I was dumb to write this code and finding the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a broadcast receivers to get the list of available wifi networks.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mWifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
                List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();

            }
        }
    }
```

also add these lines in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

and in oncreate() method register the listners

```
mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
registerReceiver(mWifiScanReceiver,
        new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
mWifiManager.startScan();
```

For more details this question related to this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741034/how-to-get-available-wifi-networks-and-display-them-in-a-list-in-android#18741306).

Comment: Hello Sir. If you check my code I have already added that part. And I have seen this post, that you have linked, many times, it only works in activity I have already mentioned that. Thank you.