# Xamarin Forms: Show list of Wifi Network and Connect to One

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to get the list of Wifi network for Xamarin Forms and connect to one (Both iOS and Android)?

I am getting some results from the Web but I couldn't find the connection between showing the list and connecting to one as the requirement is the SSID. And I couldn't find the SSID in the list.

Comment: Implement the function on each platform , and call it with dependency service .

Detailed solution please refer https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/02/15/connecting-wifi-xamarin-forms/.

Comment: Hi @ColeXia-MSFT, I already have seen the website. I just don't see how to get the list of wifi network and get the SSID.

Comment: have you tried these?  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27364/how-to-get-list-of-wifi-networks     https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30359/want-to-get-all-the-avaiable-wifi-network-list-using-mobile-ios-app

Comment: Let me check on those and get back to you. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @PaulaKristin, did you find any solution?

Comment: @abpatil yes. Please see below.

Comment: @PaulaKristin I am able to show list in android but not in iPhone, I am looking for iPhone specific code.

Comment: Hang on, no idea yet. But it might be platform specific.

Answer (score 0):

For Android:

```
wifiManager.ConfiguredNetworks.ForEach(n =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"=== WifiNetwork : {n.Ssid} ===");
                Debug.WriteLine($"=== WifiNetwork : {n.HiddenSSID} ===");
                Debug.WriteLine($"=== WifiNetwork : {n.NetworkId} ===");
                Debug.WriteLine($"=== WifiNetwork : {n.ProviderFriendlyName} ===");
            });
```

These are the saved ones

For Scanning wifi, convert this link to android code:
[How to get available wifi networks and display them in a list in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741034/how-to-get-available-wifi-networks-and-display-them-in-a-list-in-android)

Please share results for iOS.