# Get list of all wifi networks in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the following method which should retrieve all wifi networks in reach. However I get no output although there are several networks nearby.

```java
public static void getWIFI(Context context) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();

        if (results != null) {
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

            for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
                buf.append(ssid + "\n");
            }

            Log.i("Test", buf.toString());
        }
}
```

I have added the following permissions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

The device is a Pixel 3a, am I missing anything?

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947386

Comment: Did you debug the code and check if there really are SSIDs starting with `sv-`?

Comment: The error was the missing permission check that Viral linked, thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to get MAC-Address instead of the SSID?

Answer (score -1):

Mac Address

Remplace.
    `results.get(i).SSID`
For
    `results.get(i).BSSID`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult